# Cloudformation conditional nested stack Unresolved resource dependencies

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation stack that conditionally invokes a nested stack to create a RDS instance, only if an existing database URL is not passed in as a parameter.

If I pass a value to the `DBExistingEndpoint` parameter in the stack, the condition `CreateDB` is set to false, and it will not invoke the nested RDS stack at all.

The issue is that in the AutoScaling launch config resource, there is a conditional dependency. I need to reference either the URL output from the nested stack, or the URL passed in as a parameter to place in a file in the newly launched instance.

```
    Parameters:
      DBExistingEndpoint:
        Type: String
        Description: Set to a URL of a RDS instance to use an existing DB, otherwise create one
        Default: ''
    ...
    
    Conditions:
      CreateDB:
        !Equals [!Ref DBExistingEndpoint, '']
    ...

    Resources:
      # Database created only if existing URL not passed in
      DB:
        Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
        Condition: CreateDB
        Properties:
          TemplateURL: ...
      ...

      ClusterInstanceLaunchConfig:
        Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
        Metadata:
          AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
            config:

              files:
                /etc/dbenv:
                  mode: "000640"
                  owner: root
                  group: root
                  content:
                    !Join
                      - "\n"
                      -
                        - !Sub ["DB_HOST=${DBEndpointAddress}", DBEndpointAddress: !If [CreateDB, !GetAtt DB.Outputs.RDSEndPointAddress, !Ref DBExistingEndpoint]]
                      ...
```

The issue is that if I pass in an existing endpoint URL, the DB resource is skipped (correctly), but the stack creation fails with `Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [DB] in the Resources block of the template`

Ideally the `DB.output.RDSEndpointAddress` reference in the `ClusterInstanceLauchConfig` resource should be ignored because the `CreateDB` condition in the `!If` is false

Does anybody know how to code around this limitation?

Comment: It turns out that the !If statement does indeed work correctly, there was another DependsOn: reference to the DB resource further down the script.

Comment: If you solved the issue, you can answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the conditional statement on a different level than it is now.

What will work for sure, is having the conditional statement on the level of the `LaunchConfiguration` itself, which would also mean quite a lot of duplication of the code. But maybe you could try to see the conditional on the level of `content` or `files` etc, to see if there's a middle ground somewhere, to keep duplication low, but avoid the error you're getting right now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I spent a few hours coming up with a convoluted workaround using SSM parameter store, but then discovered an error in the template with an unbound DependsOn: DB way down the template (it has 2000+ lines!). If only AWS errors were more specific about which line of code had the issue.